# HTML - Input check with javascript that stops PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is probably a bit of an odd question, but I've got some odd circumstances. 
Basically I've got an html page with text inputs, which are intended to match certain inputs with an SQL database, but the inputs must be checked for null first. It's a sort of mock-up login system using only usernames.

My problem comes from the fact that I'm required to use PHP only for database queries and passing of values such as what is in the text fields. As such I set the form to have the php as its action, and made a javascript file the runs its code first and checks for null. The javascript works just fine, but after the alert it returns is closed the php page is loaded (It doesn't contain any code yet as I need to tackle this first).

Does anyone know how I can resolve it so the user is forced back onto the page with the PHP and javascripts reset? I tried a few javascript commands that attempt to reload the page but the PHP still activated. I read that AJAX could possibly handle this, but I've had a ton of trouble getting JQuery to work for some reason.

Sorry for the really odd question, Honestly it'd be nice if I could just use PHP for this. Anyways, thanks for any and all help, really appreciated!

JavaScript:

```
function loginEmpty() {
    var login = document.getElementById("profileName").innerHTML;
    if (login==null || login=="")
    {
        alert("You did not enter a username");
        return false;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="YSP.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">

<h1>You SHALL Pass!</h1>

</div>

<div id="navBar" class="mainScheme">

<!--Navbar content goes here-->

</div>

<div id="main" class ="mainScheme">

<h2>User Login</h2>

<!--Old user login - name match from DB-->
<form id="loginForm" action="You_Shall_Pass.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Log in to a profile</legend>

<label for="profileName">User name: </label>
<input id="profileName" name="profileName" type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="loginButton" name="loginButton" value="Log in!" onclick="loginEmpty();" />

</fieldset>
</form>

<!--New user login - Creates a new user in DB-->
<form id="loginForm" action="You_Shall_Pass.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>New user? Create a user name here!</legend>

<label for="newProfileName">User name:</label>
<input id="newProfileName" name="newProfileName" type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="createButton" name="createButton" value="Create!" onclick="newUserEmpty();" />

</fieldset>
</form>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a button/input element of `type="submit"` inside a form is clicked, the form encapsulating that button will do a call to the form's `action` attribute. If you don't want this to happen, you could use a `<div>` element and style it with CSS to make it look like a button. When the div gets clicked the form will not be submitted.

If you want JQuery to work, include the following two lines to your head tag

```
<script src="/path/to/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/scripts/yourjsfile.js"></script>
```

Replace your submit button with `<div id="SubmitButton"></div>`.

Then inside your javascript file you put

```
$(function(){ // $ means JQuery, so its a shortcut for JQuery(document).ready()

     $("#SubmitButton").click(function(){
     // function will run when SubmitButton is clicked
     var DataIsValid = false;

     if(/*Perform your checks here */)
         DataIsValid = true;

     //end function if checks failed
     if(!DataIsValid)
         return;

     //perform an ajax call to send your data to the 
     //webserver where you can execute your PHP code
     });

});
```

Comment: I could try this, but I'm not 100% sure how it would work in my case. I still need to form to send the data over to php and run the function I'm going to code. Would it be possible for a div to be able to do the same, but with the javascript function interrupting beforehand and stopping the php function if the input was null?

Comment: That is exactly the case. Let me edit my answer for you.

Comment: @Alzecha I hope this will suffice for now. Do some research on what AJAX is etc. If you have any questions I can answer them tomorrow. I'm going to sleep now. Cya buddy.